Optimal setup for ±15V dual rail power supply from USB-C
I have a decent +15V power supply design from USB-C, however I also need a low noise stable -15V supply. What approach would be optimal to convert +15V to -15V, or +16V to -16V to a -15V LDO?
It's for a sensitive audio circuit (AK4499EXEQ DAC output), but it only needs to power 4 NE5532N op-amps, so low current at about 80mA, but low ripple is important.

Can you add more details to your question about the current and ripple requirements on the new -15V rail?

Seb - Hi, I note you have edited the question to remove the off-topic recommendation request. Can you add the details of what you mean by low noise & stable for that -15 V rail, as well as the current requirements (as requested in the comment above)? Then it should be suitable for reopening. TY

Absolutely. It's for a sensitive audio circuit, but it only needs to power 4 NE5532N op-amps, so low current at about 80mA, but low ripple is important. Thanks guys!
Edit: To specify it's for a AK4499EXEQ DAC output.

@Seb - Thanks, I added those details into the question & reopened it, as it is no longer off-topic. If you had an actual ripple specification, that would be even better. However now knowing the application, site members may be able to recommend typical solutions. (If you do have a ripple specification, please [edit] the question to add it, rather than putting it in a comment. TY)

There are many different options for power converters out there, with several vendors having their own "power design" tools for selecting components.
Topology-wise you'll need some from of inverting DC-DC regulator - depending on the power levels required that could be one of any number of inductor based DC-DCs, or even switched-capacitor designs for low-power applications.
For low noise, you'll most likely want to consider stepping up to a higher voltage (e.g. +/-16V as you suggest), then filter and use a pair of low-noise high-PSSR LDOs - one for positive rail and one for negative rail. This will help reduce ripple from the DC-DC if selected properly (e.g. switching frequency of DC-DC within the high PSSR region of the LDO).

Fantastic. I already stepped up my +15V rail to +16V for the LDO, whoever I have been uncertain about component selection for the negative rail as it is quite new to me to actually need negative supply. I just need to power 4 NE5533N opamps. Could you guide me in the right direction?
